# React router v4 default page being rendered everytime

Tags: reactjs, react-router-v4

I'm trying to get a default page working, but what happens is that it is being rendered everytime. It's like the `Switch` doesn't stop only at the first route matched.

Here is my code:

index.js

```
ReactDOM.render(
    <BrowserRouter>
        <Provider store={store}>
            <Switch>
                <App/>
            </Switch>
        </Provider>
    </BrowserRouter>,
    document.getElementById("root")
);
```

App.js

```
class App extends React.Component {
    ...
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <AppGuest location={location}/>
                <GuestRoute location={location} component={ReservationsPage}/>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

AppGuest.js

```
class AppGuest extends React.Component {
    componentDidMount() {
    }

    render() {
        const { location} = this.props;
        return (
            <div>
                <GuestRoute exact location={location} path="/" component={ReservationsPage}/>

                <GuestRoute exact location={location} path="/login" component={LoginPage}/>
                <GuestRoute exact location={location} path="/signup" component={SignupPage}/>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

and here is my GuestRoute.js

```
const GuestRoute = ({  component: Component, ...rest }) => (
  <Route
    {...rest}
    render={props =>
        <div>
            <Navigation/>
            <Component {...props} />
        </div>
    }
  />
);
```

Is it possible that because I have so many divs the `Switch` is not able to properly detect the routes?

Edit: Tried replacing the `<div>` with `<React.Fragment>` and `[]` structures, but I still have the same problem.

I guess I will just have a huge index file with all the routes there.

Answer (score 0):

There are several issues with your code.

Your first GuestRoute (in App) has no path attribute, so it will *always* match. [See here.](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Route/path-string)

As for Switch statements, *all of their children should be Route or Redirect elements*. [See here.](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Switch/children-node)

Comment: The Guest Route does have a path attribute. Read the code again. As for the second sentence, I will check now.

Comment: Indeed you are right about the `Switch`. If I get rid of the divs and put all routes inside it it is going to work. I ll try to find something else to wrap routes in.

Comment: @BogdanDaniel I was referring to the GuestRoute in App.js, not the ones in  AppGuest.js. It has no path attribute, so it will match everytime.

Comment: As for Switch vs. div, Switch makes all children route exclusive, so it will render the first Route that matches and ignore the others. However, if you use the `exact` attribute in your Routes, you can achieve the same result even if they are enclosed in a div instead of a Switch.

Comment: Personally, I use always use Switch to enclose Routes except in those rare cases where I want multiple Routes to match a given URL (for example if I want to have a contextual sidebar appear over multiple pages).